# Negative voltage using boost converter

Tags: voltage-regulator

I am referring a schematic where 16V,10.4V,-7v is generated from [TPS61040](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps61040.pdf)

[image: Voltage]

R12 and R17 are used to set 16V from TPS61040 IC and zener diode is used to generate 10.4V.

But how -7V is generated, I am not getting. Please someone guide. 
Thanks.

Comment: the use of zeners as voltage droppers is somewhat unorthodox.  series regulators like 78Lxx 79Lxx would give better regulation.

Comment: Agree.. but, required voltages are not available with 78lxx or 79lxx series IC's.

Comment: @Jasen good point, that didn't even register as I was focused on the charge pump.

Comment: @Electroholic  octopart.com can find most things, including 79L07 and 78L10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of it like a single-action pump. The capacitor blocks DC voltage, so the only thing going through is an AC waveform (\$\approx V_{OUT}\$ peak-to-peak, as seen at the switching node).

On the falling edge, current is sucked through D1, and during the rising edge, current is pushed through D3. Since current is being pulled from the top side of C5 and being deposited at ground, a negative voltage develops across C5.

D2 and R10 are then used to control the output voltage in the same way that D5 and R11 are used to control the positive output voltage.

Comment: So, above schematic seems correct ..Right? I am concerned because I am seeing it first time where -7V is generated from boost converter. ( PS: All these voltages ie 16V,10.4V and -7V are used for LCD's VGH,AVDD and VGL pins respectively )

Comment: Eh, I'm not vouching for its correctness, just its plausibility... :)

Comment: yeah I agree, it looks to me like an ordinary charge pump fed from the changing voltage that's found at the switched end of the inductor.

Comment: The 16 V supply is regulated, but the -7 V charge pump is not, so the -7 V supply might vary as you draw more or less current from the 16 V supply.